# How to store data in the project

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I will be using GridViews in my application and other data containers but I do not want to use MSSQL or anything like that as it is a simple program.. Can I store the data in someway in the project itself? as my data souce? Like for instance I can have a class called Employee and I want to store the employee information (data) somewhere within the project and then be able to grab it anytime i want.. without the need of using MSSQL or any database system. Is there something like this?

Comment: Think this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606959/how-to-store-data-without-using-database-and-how-to-retrieve-them

Comment: Can SQL CE be used in Windows Forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try SQL compact edition, See http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx

Comment: This looks great but, can it be used in Windows Forms?

Comment: Yes, it should. Reference: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/30/new-embedded-database-support-with-asp-net.aspx Scott Gu: "You can actually use SQL CE 3.5 with winforms and wpf client applications today.  It supports embedding it with the application and xcopy deployment already for client scenarios.

Hope this helps,

Scott" The latest release is 4.0 I believe.

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider either XML files, or sql compact edition (which is similar, but not the same as SQL server) - both are very easy to use for small amounts of data. SQL CE just requires a couple of DLL's if I remember correctly (and its free)

Comment: Can it be used in Windows Forms?

Answer (score 1):

Flat files, or XML for more structured data are probably the best bets.