# XML to list using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

have an XML file like this:

```
<VS>
  <Fields>
    <Field Id="$1*">Column1</Field>
    <Field Id="$2*">Column2</Field>
    <Field Id="$3*">Column3</Field>
  </Fields>
</VS>
```

When I use LINQ to XML using the following statement:

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(s);
var q = doc.Descendants("Fields").ToList();
```

I get a single entry in list as Column1Column2Column3, whereas I want it as 3 separate entities like Column1, Column2, Column3.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Field` instead of `Fields`:

```
var q = doc.Descendants("Field").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use **XElement.Parse(BuildNode.InnerXml)** instead of just passing the raw property in.

[Check This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2607043/1358004)

Answer (score 0):

Just used the following code which returned list of strings.

**var q = doc.Descendants("Field").Select(x => x.Value);**

Thanks for all your suggestions!