# Loading html textbox values with an external text file

Tags: javascript, forms, file, textbox, txt

I am curious if something is possible or would it be too much security risk. I have been working on making an online game and part of that game is the Player Character sheet that keeps up with health, items, coins, etc. inside a bunch of text boxes, and this information changes throughout the game. There is a lot of information.

I have seen several methods to save all this information into a text file on the player's device but was curious if there is a way to load all that information back into the correct textboxes from the same file that was saved so the player does not have to retype everything every time they restart a game. I feel there is a security reason this can't be done but I thought I would ask. Here is a picture of the character sheet being worked on.
[image]

---

ok, I have found an example of what I have been trying to do. Problem is that the code only works with one text area box and when I try to play with the code to add more input boxes, it only saves one portion of the entire value into the text file and when I upload that text file, it puts that one value into every box. I have played with this code for a bit but I can not figure out how to make it save information from multiple text boxes and text areas into a file, and be able to read that file in a way that it could put the correct values into each text box or textarea again.

I am placing the bit of code that does work below to see if anybody knows where I am going wrong. Thanks

```
<html>
  <body>

  <table>
  <tr><td>Text to Save:</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <textarea id="inputTextToSave" cols="80" rows="25"> 
        </textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Filename to Save As:</td>
    <td><input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"></input></td>
    <td><button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save Text to 
        File</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Select a File to Load:</td>
    <td><input type="file" id="fileToLoad"></td>
    <td><button onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load Selected 
        File</button><td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

function saveTextAsFile()
{
var textToSave = 
document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], 
{type:"text/plain"});
var textToSaveAsURL = 
window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
var fileNameToSaveAs = 
document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;

var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
downloadLink.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}

function loadFileAsText()
{
var fileToLoad = 
document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];

var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
{
    var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
    document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = 
textFromFileLoaded;
};
fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you will [find this SO thread helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606959/how-to-store-data-without-using-database-and-how-to-retrieve-them).

Comment: Thanks, I have taken a look at it and so far.... I understand nothing about it. It does point me in a direction, maybe with some studying, I will figure it out.